# javascript save/load image + text data from client side

Tags: javascript, image, load, save, blob

I want users of my page to be able to save and load data (single file) which contains images and numerical values.

I've found how to save image

```
saveImgAs = function (img, fileName) {
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', img.src);
    a.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    a.click();
}
```

and text files

```
saveTextAsFile = function (textToWrite, fileNameToSaveAs) {
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], { type: 'text/plain' });

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }
    downloadLink.click();
};

destroyClickedElement = function(event) {
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
};
```

but I don't know how to merge them to one file and how to load that structure back..
    Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for Web Storage, a new feature of HTML5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage. It will ultimately make your entire process easier and require fewer hack-like solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Like Zeal said, just use the Web-Storage of HTML5 ( aka "local storage" ).
Nowadays almost all browsers support it. Here a short example:

```
// Check if it is supported in your browser
function supports_html5_storage()
{
      try
      {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        return false;
      }
}

//make use of it:
if( supports_html5_storage() == true )
{
   localStorage.setItem("myItem", "myData");
   var myDataString = localStorage.getItem("myItem");
   alert(myDataString);
}
```

Comment: How could be this an answer?! The output must be a single file what the user can open, not a local storage entity, what the average user doesn't have a clue. Or if I miss something can you elaboate it?

Comment: It seems to be no requirement that the users can open the single file by their own. Op just asks for a way to load/save from/to a single file. Actually the DB-entity even is a single file.

Answer (score 0):

I use the WebStorage API and localStorage to save and load the game saves of my js games, so I don't know much about saving and loading a file, but this should help you save it as one file, which seems to be the crux of this question.

Convert your image to base64 string.

[How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Save your image string and numerical values to a single object.

Use JSON.stringify() method to convert the object to a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Save the JSONstring as a file.

[Writing a json object to a text file in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055598/writing-a-json-object-to-a-text-file-in-javascript)

When you load the file use JSON.parse() to restore it to an object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse