# document.write and JSON output

Tags: javascript, json

I have some big json configs and want allow users to export them. The problem is JS `prompt` cant return a full data, so i decided to use windows.open and write. But "write" just "eat" html in json values. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055706 helped a lot.

```
var data = Store.export();
var url = 'data:text/json;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
window.open(url, '_blank');
window.focus();
```

But when i try to export really large and long json everything freezes... 
How can i modify it to use blank url and unmodified json as text?

**UPD**
My workaround

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "JSON Settings", '_blank');
myWindow.document.write('<textarea>' + escapeHTML(Store.export()) + '</textarea>');
myWindow.focus();
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for us to test around with?

Comment: Did you try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server (second answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include a multi-line text field in which you would place the data.

This gives it a space to go rather than just being injected into the HTML.

The user would then copy and paste the data out into their own `.json` file.

Comment: I used to do this, but large amounts of data has caused my browser to hang a few times, so I switched to sending the data as a download and had better results.

Comment: Yeah. it looks great, and did what i want with html, but this kind of data - &quot;news&quot; transformed into "news" and broke json...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to export the data, do you have any requirements prohibiting the user from downloading the data?

This lib has come in handy for me several times:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: I was thinking bout this, but dont want use external library :c